# mvc razor editable DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I am looking for a code to make the dropdown list editable in MVC razor.
@Html.DropDownList provides the standard select list, but the values are not editable.

I tried an example from a tutorial, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

First need to add the script reference to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.editable-select.pack.js"></script>
```

This If you host this script on your server.

You only need to set the id on you razor definition of the dropdown and then do this:

```
$('#nameOfDropDown').editableSelect({...});
```

After doing this and checking the documentation of this plugin you might be able to get a editable select list.