# Editable DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm looking for a solution to add an editable DropDownList to an ASP.NET MVC 5.1 project. User should be able to type in new values or select from a list of existing ones. There are plenty of solutions out there but none of them worked well enough for me:

1. http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/ mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405130/mvc-razor-editable-dropdownlist) question - 404 error so I can't try this one.
2. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox - I've found a NuGet package called jQuery.UI.Widgets.Autocomplete but NuGet installer throws an error "Updating 'jQuery 2.1.0' to 'jQuery 1.4.4' failed. Unable to find versions of 'bootstrap, jQuery.UI.Combined' that are compatible with 'jQuery 1.4.4'." (as you can see I'm using jQuery 2.1 in the project so I'd preferably not downgrade to 1.4.4). When I just manually included the script, it throws JavaScript exception about .combobox() being undefined, but maybe I'm doing something wrong here.
3. https://bitbucket.org/RaYell/jquery-jec - doesn't work well in IE (or at least version 11). Pressing space opens the list instead of just typing it in. Unfortunately I have to support this browser.

Does anyone have a working solution for MVC 5 or above to get this kind of widget?

Comment: You don't *have* to use the nuget package. If it's requiring jQuery 1.4.4, that means it's abandonware anyways. Just add the scripts manually.

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes, but I tried that and it throws a JS exception saying that .combobox() is not defined. :S

Comment: Then you have a JS error. Most likely you're trying to call combobox() at some point before it's actually loaded. Always put your script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Ok I'll give it one more try and report back. Thanks.